# To connect to SharePoint Online Client Context using browser credentials from powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, client-object-model, csom

I am using below code to connect to SPO from powershell, but we have multi factor authentication in SharePoint.

So I want to give credentials from browser instead of script. Please suggest as i dont want to use PnP and Connect-SPOService due to environment restrictions.

```
{
    $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl)
    $ctx.Credentials=New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName,$password)
        return $ctx
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an app password for your user using [these steps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-app-password-for-Office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Then you will be able to connect using your username and app password instead of a real password.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do that, as probably our client will not permit me to create app password and i have to run this powershell script from a remote machine? After entering the email address in during logging in to SPO site, it asks our domain\userid and password again in a pop up, so i assume this is not a multi-factor authentication.

Comment: Ah I got it. No it's not MFA

Comment: I'm not aware of any other good way to do that when MFA is enabled. The other way is PnP-PS of course, but you can't use it...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try the app password yet, but this worked for me

```
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
```